a very light menu appears even after toggling off the menu in vscode
When i try to right click and the normal menu appears but then when i click somewhere else, a light shade of the menu still remains.
semi transparent context menu
this also is the same for the suggestions menu in vscode
semi transparent suggesstion menu
i was modifiying the settings and animations in vscode and i stumbled upon this issue which is very irratating. i also have installed the following extentions.
extentions list

Welcome! 1) if you scroll, does it go away? if so, it's probably some sort of rendering bug. 2) Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post. 3) Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled command in the command palette)? If not, then do an extension bisect to figure out what extension is causing it.

i reset all the settings and then reinstalled vscode along with all the extentions and now it's fixed thanks. anyways thanks

what extensions had you installed? their contents should still be on disk under ~/.vscode/extensions/. can you list the names of the directories you see in there?

there are 16 folders and their list is as follows:
link
i think the issue is not with the extensions but with the settings. i remember toggling on and off random features in the settings and i guess that's the cause
